# Как развернуть локальную сеть geth

Tags: cmd

Я пишу контракт для ethereum. Обычно я запускаю geth с этими параметрами

```
"C:\Program Files\Geth\geth" --dev  --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpc --minerthreads "1" --rpcapi "admin,debug,miner,shh,txpool,personal,eth,net,web3" --datadir "gethtmp" console
```

После открываю Ethereum Wallet. Там он сам подхватывает работающий geth и позволяет писать контракт

[image: Ethereum wallet]

**При этом, чтобы действие в контракте заработало, нужен майнинг!!! Создавать свой genesis.json бесполезно, я не хочу сорить файлами и огромная сумма эфира на кошельке не нужна, а нужен ПРОЦЕСС МАЙНИНГА**

Чтобы протестировать контракт нужно подключится к такой сети с другого компьютера? Кто нибудь решал проблему?

Если следовать инструкции из гитхаба ethereum, то вместо майнинга происходит такая хрень
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Geth сам висит с такой строкой. Майнинга не происходит, происходит забивание диска откровенным бредом. Вместо майнинга получаю лаги на PC

```
INFO [08-18|19:41:09] Generating DAG in progress               epoch=1 percentage=2 elapsed=13.423s
```

Прошу, не посылайте меня на читать мануал, нужно конкретное решение проблемы. Либо у меня плохо с английским или делаю что-то не то. Я уже пытался воспроизвести, но видимо ошибаюсь в процессе

Comment: Использовать тестовую сеть - плохой вариант, ибо интернет модемный, а база весит 30 гигабайт. Задача развернуть свою сеть именно по локалке

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: в документации описано как создать свою сеть https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network